# My GameObject(Sword) in Unity does not bind to Player (AnotherGameObject). It stays at (0f, 0f, 0f)

Tags: c#, topdown

I want to make my sword bind to the player butwhen I hit Play and move my character, the sword just moves around for like one float value and then snaps back to its original position(0,0,0). I also want to add a sword offset.

**Code:**

```
public GameObject Player;
public GameObject Self;
public Vector3 SwordOffset;

void FixedUpdate ()
{ 
Self.transform.position = Player.transform.postion;
//I have not added the offset yet.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. Ok first of all don't use the fixedUpdate methode . Second the sword you pic up in the game or you start with it ?
if you pic it up while playing you make sure that you make an empty game object under your player gameobject (called **equipment holder**) and when you pic your equipment(sword , shield , bow , book ...) you delete it from the world and create a clone of it under the empty gameobject (**equipment holder**) and reset the transform of this equipment (sword , shield , bow , book ...) and you should be set. if you are using an animation this won't work and the transform will be reset to the animation transform.

I can help you more if you need anymore assistance please mail me

Comment: I start with the sword and I found out what I was doing wrong. I was not capitalising properly. Thank you for your help as I will be using your tip when I need to change weapons.